# How to get a link from a website Button in Android Java

Tags: java, android, web, button, hyperlink

Basically what I want is. There is a button on a website that leads to a link, the link that the button leads to changes frequently, how do I get the latest link from that button that is on a website, from Android Studio. Also, I don't own that website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Jsoup**, it runs on Java 7 and up, Kotlin and Android.

follow instruction in this [parse html](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links), it show how to fetch a page from a URL; extract links, images, and other pointers; and examine their URLs and text.

You will be able to get the link each time he changed by getting to parent div of this block of html code and search the href link for example...

Good luck.